# Limelight CDN PHP upload interface code

Tags: php, cdn

Does any one out there have any php example code to upload files from a php form to the Limelight CDN?

Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 1):

The following article contains the detailed steps for Content API reference for developers for uploading media files to PHP.

Hope this helps.

http://www.delvenetworks.com/support/docs/

Answer (score 0):

FTP, webdav, origin pull? Kind of hard to guess what you are after. For origin pull (or the transparent proxy setup), you don't need any scripts.

Let me know, and I'll be happy to extend my answer.